# Bison error handling

Tags: bison, yacc, parser-generator

I have a problem with Bison's error handling. I have the following grammar (I have cut out only the relevant part). Flex sends its tokens to Bison and returns the terminal symbol "KW_CONFIGPARAM" if the string "ConfigParam" is parsed. IDENT is a pointer to a C++ string object.

```
statementlist   : statement ';'               { $$ = new string("statementlist"); }
                | statementlist statement ';' { $$ = new string("statementlist"); }
;
statement       : KW_CONFIGPARAM IDENT        { $$ = new string("statement"); /* use $2, IDENT is used in main program */ }
;
```

I have the following destructor specified for strings like IDENT.

%destructor { printf ("free at line %d: %s\n",@$.first_line, $$->c_str()); delete($$); }

Now I have the following input. The first line is valid, the second line isn't (identifier is missing):

```
ConfigParam p;
ConfigParam;
```

Output:

```
In input 2:12 - 2:12 : syntax error
free at line 2: p
free at line 1: statementlist
```

Because of an error in the second line, Bison complains, returns a syntax error and calls the destructors of all objects on the parsing stack.
Now I don't understand why the destructor of identifier "p" from the first line is called? It belongs to the first line and it was successfully parsed. The problem is that p is used in the main program and should be not removed by Bison.

If I choose as an (invalid) statement an arbitrary string ("foo") p is not removed by Bison.

```
ConfigParam p;
foo;

In input 2:1 - 2:3 : syntax error
free at line 1: statementlist
free at line 2: foo
```

Why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to tell the exact problem without seeing more of your file, but it's certainly not the case that

> The first line was successfully parsed and should be popped off the stack

The stack at the point of the error looks like this:

```
statementlist KW_CONFIGPARAM
```

where `statementlist` was created by the reduction of the first line, as reported by bison.

You don't seem to be specifying a value for statement_list; if you excerpt is literal, then it will have been compiled as though it had been written:

```
statementlist   : statement ';'                 {$0 = $1;}
```

I can't tell what the value corresponding to `statement` was, but it is certainly conceivable that it includes the string `"p"`. That depends on what you set `$0` to during `{ /* do some stuff, create a new ConfigParam object */ }`.

(Moved from a comment once it became evident that it's somewhat close to the right answer.)
My other idea is this: Perhaps you've made all of your terminals and non-terminals have a type which triggers that destructor. And maybe your lexer does not modify `yylval` when it returns `KW_CONFIGPARM`. In that case, the bison parser cannot know that `yylval` is irrelevant, so it will use the left over `yylval` (which is a pointer to `"p"`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I rewrite the example and I hope it is more clear now. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @user4811: My other idea is this: Perhaps you've made all of your terminals and non-terminals have a type which triggers that destructor. And maybe your lexer does not modify `yylval` when it returns `KW_CONFIGPARM`. In that case, the bison parser cannot know that `yylval` is irrelevant, so it will use the left over yylval (which is a pointer to `p`). Again, I'm really just guessing because I can see so little of your project.

Answer (score 1):

@rici: Thanks a lot, you point me to the right direction. I have written

```
%token <str>    STRING    IDENT       NUMBER
                KW_CONFIGPARAM
```

but correct is of course...

```
%token <str>    STRING    IDENT       NUMBER
%token          KW_CONFIGPARAM
```

Arrghhh!

@rici: You have made my day!!!